# cwrsync in windows not being recognised

Tags: windows, rsync, cwrsync

I am trying to move from a mac environment to a windows one and require rsync.

Found cwrsync @ http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html

I have installed the cwrsync program fine, I can call the rsync at cmd but on when in the directory which contains the sync.exe

When in command prompt, if i call rsync when not in the relavent directory it moans and sayS:

> "rsync" is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Is there a way to add the rsync.exe to a global list so as rsync is recognised outside of its immediate parent directory?

Thanks,
John

[image: rsync not working.]

Comment: For anyone who lands on this today.. years on i have learned (to not use windows) to just use cygwin instead of cwrsync and just install the rsync module into cygwin.  https://www.cygwin.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the path in the Windows system variables:

```
- Control Panel -> System -> tab Advanced, button Environment Variables.
- Edit the "Path" system variable and add the full path to the installed rsync:
     C:\Program Files\cwRsync\bin or C:\cygwin\bin. or
     C:\Program Files (x86)\cwRsync\bin or C:\cygwin\bin.
```

This way the commands rsync and ssh should run from any directory. Make sure you put in the correct install path to the application else it won't work. See screenshot below:

Environment Variable Setup: Make sure the path you added is under System Variables:

[image]

Command: As seen, I am running this directly from root of C: drive

[image]

Comment: ok, i have created a system variable: "rsync" with value: "C:\Program Files\cwRsync\bin\rsync.exe". I have restarted the machine but no joy. Upon calling the rsync command outside of the directory holding the .exe file it still moans with the same message.

Comment: are you running a 64bit machine or 32bit? Also can you confirm the install location is Program Files or Program Files (x86)

Comment: Win7 pro 64bit sp1. The install location of rsync is: "C:\Program Files\cwRsync\bin\rsync.exe".

Comment: See my updates. This is no rocket science, it should work if you did it well

Comment: yea i did think so, please see my original post. I have followed your instructions but still no joy. i have attached a screenshot, can you see anything wrong with what i have implemented?

Comment: Ahhhh... i get it! I though that i had to create a brand new entry. Did not realise you had to add to the existing "path" variable.

Answer (score 0):

cwRsync distribution contains a batch file example called **cwrsync.cmd** with correct path settings. You can simply add your rsync command into that file.